# is inertia important?

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Like do we need to add inertia to urdf, like when I just set it 0 it still works but when I set to some value it explodes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379310/is-inertia-important?/) by [harish556](https://answers.ros.org/users/60452/harish556/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2021-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Inertia is mainly important in simulation. If you are just using a URDF for visualization in RVIZ then it really doesn't matter. If you use a URDF to drive simulation (such as using it in gazebo) then it does matter. `inertia` tags in a URDF are the 3d tensor moments of inertia. This can be calculated with most mainstream CAD packages for complex geometry. If the geometry is simple you could also calculate it yourself using the formulas from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia#List_of_3D_inertia_tensors).

EDIT: Some more info is available on the [ros wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Adding%20Physical%20and%20Collision%20Properties%20to%20a%20URDF%20Model#Inertia) as well

As stated the inertia is a 3d tensor so it should have multiple fields. See example below:

Consider a sphere with mass of 10.5kg, and radius of 0.5 meters.

The tensor for a sphere is:

[image: sphere_tensor]

So along the diagonal, the values should be 2/5 * m * r^2 => 2/5 * 10.5 * 0.5^2 = 1.05

The `inertial` tag for this would look like:

```
<inertial>
  <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <mass value="10.5"/>
  <inertia
    ixx="1.05"  ixy="0.00"  ixz="0.00"
    iyx="0.00"  iyy="1.05"  iyz="0.00"
    izx="0.00"  izx="0.00"  izz="1.05"
  />
</inertial>
```

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [djchopp](https://answers.ros.org/users/74140/djchopp/) with karma: 328 on 2021-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [harish556](https://answers.ros.org/users/60452/harish556/) on 2021-06-02**:
thanks alot

**Comment by [iamsdevaprasad](https://answers.ros.org/users/147538/iamsdevaprasad/) on 2023-07-22**:
Hi could you please share the sources from where you found that inertia will not be used in Rviz. Thank you.